# Cricket Scoring Website + Asp.net MVC + Auto Update Scores & Run statics

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am working on project which have functionality like Creating Team, Tournament, Play Match between teams and also scoring that match.... via web and mobile application....

So I have to implement a functionality like if a scorer enters a score immediately the scores updates on scorecard or player statics are reflected with new values,

I am using Asp.net MVC 3.0, MS SQL 2008 and Entity Framework, jQuery etc.

So please anybody can guide to achieve above functionality while taking care of site performance...

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is real time updates for an already rendered page I would use SignalR. It allows you to push data from an MVC app to a webpage. JavaScript on the website can then update the content in real time. Lookup single page application and SignalR

Here is a guide to getting started with it http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is **SignalR**

ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to your applications. Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server-side code push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available.

You may have heard of the HTML5 WebSocket API that enables efficient bidirectional communication between the browser and server. SignalR uses Websockets when it is supported by the browser and the server, and gracefully falls back to other techniques and technologies when it is not. Either way, your application code stays the same.

SignalR provides a simple ASP.NET API for creating server-to-client remote procedure calls (RPC) that call JavaScript functions in client browsers from server-side .NET code. SignalR also includes API for connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events), grouping connections, and authorization.

[More about SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

[Sample](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)